# JPA @Type annotation "Cannot resolve method 'type' "

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I was working on a project and found that on the @Type interface, there is no method called type. Is there any way to resolve the error?

[image: Cannot resolve method 'type']

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Delivery_Table")
public class Delivery {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "Delivery_Id")
    private Long id;

    @Nationalized
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "address_full",length = 500)
    private String address;
    private LocalTime Delivery_time;
    //Problem occurs here
    //Configuration on pom.xml used JPA where Hibernate is already there
    @Type(type = "yes_no")
    private Boolean completed;

}
```

Comment: What's your import statement for `Type`?

Comment: import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess that you are using Hibernate 6 ?

If yes, the source codes you show is for Hibernate 5 or before. Hibernate 6 has the breaking change in the type system , there are no more `type` attribute in the `@Type` , you have to migrate it to use the related JPA standard `AttributeConverter` (i.e `YesNoConverter`) according to the [migration guide](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/migration-guide/migration-guide.html#_boolean_converters) :

> Hibernate now provides standard AttributeConverter implementations for
> handling different database representations as boolean values in the
> domain model

Change to the following should solve your problem :

```java
 @Convert(converter=YesNoConverter.class)
 private Boolean completed;
```

Comment: Well. I'm not separately using Hibernate. The dependency I'm using is **spring data jpa**. I don't know which version of hibernate is included on data JPA.

`<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>`

Comment: spring-data-jpa will include hibernate automatically. what version of spring-boot ? on the other hands , most IDE provides easy way to check which version of hibnerate you are using

Comment: Spring boot version: 3.1.2 I'm using

Comment: ok then you are using hibernate 6. so follow my suggestion to fix it.and if you think my post is helpful to you, please consider to upvote it or accept the answer as i spend lot of my time to help you for free. thanks

Comment: Hibernate 5.3.7.final is used. I'm not using Hibernate 6

Comment: Thank you for your time. But I'm not using Hibernate 6. I haven't find that useful. Because Type interface don't have any method called **converter**

Comment: no ideas how to configure your project. please show `pom.xml`. Also , spring boot 3.1 is supposed to work with hibernate 6 . Not a good idea to me if forcing it to work with hibernate 5 . One of the major reason is hibernate 5 is still using old `javax.persistence` while spring boot 3 already upgrade it to the new ` `jakarta.persistence`. And mixing `javax.persistence`  and `jakarta.persistence` in one project is really not a good idea ....

Comment: Here the code: https://github.com/XSakibxHossainX/Data_in_Mulitier_Architecture

Comment: OK. Then you are using hibernate 6 . No idea why you say you are hibernate 5.3.7...  What cause you think it is using hibernate 5.3.7 ? Also no idea what do you mean about `Type` interface does not have a method call converter . I am saying  to change it from `@Type` to `@Convert`.

Comment: Again , if you finally find my post or comments are helpful to you , please consider to upvote or accept my answer as i spend lot of my time to help you for free. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I found that - Spring Boot 3.0.0 depends on hibernate-core 6.1.5.Final.

Source -> https://spring.io/blog/2023/05/18/spring-boot-3-1-0-available-now

The reason I made the mistake Hibernate 5.3.7.final I said because I over-trusted AI. Apologize.

Comment: This is what I mean by interface 

`@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Type {
    Class<? extends UserType<?>> value();

    Parameter[] parameters() default {};
}`

Comment: good to know. that is called annotation but not interface. It have the symbol `@` before the `interface`